# Can I encounter the Mandragoras again?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-12

The Zodiac Age's Bestiary tends to have multiple-paged entries for monsters and creatures in the Bestiary. These additional pages can be obtained by killing a certain number of the referenced creature.

Currently, the Mandragoras all have 12s next to their entries, indicating that there is more information to be had about them. Is it possible to encounter them again after your fight with them in the Sochen Cave Palace?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer please don't remove the PS4 tag. There is no tag specifically for The Zodiac Age, so the original tag plus PS4 should be enough distinction.

Comment: Are they different enough to warrant two different tags?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I would say so. The Zodiac Age and the original game from 2006 have different mechanics and such.

Comment: Then make two different tags, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you mean the boss-level enemies Alraune King, Onion Queen, Mandragora Prince, Pumpkin Star and Topstalk, rather than the regular enemy Mandragora.

I ran across them again much later in the game, in the Feywood, while I was attempting to get the Behemoth King to spawn. They're in the second-to-last area before Giruvegan, "Ice Field of Clearsight". Not the one with the actual Giruvegan door but the other one with the mirage temple things. My guess was that they appear after you kill every other enemy in the area, leave and come back. [Wikia agrees.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mandragora_Prince_(Final_Fantasy_XII)#Feywood_spawning_method)

Comment: Ah I missed that section. Perfect, thank you! I've since learned that completing the beastiary only requires a single kill on each enemy type, so thankfully I don't have to worry!